# Django Foreign Key QuerySet (join)

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

So I'm learning Django and trying to get values throught foreign key by using Django ORM functions only. I've got 2 tables: User Table (default Django auth_user system table) and Student Table containing student_id, user_id(FK) and nr_indeksu (it's a number containing additional info for student specific information).

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nr_indeksu = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user
```

I want to fetch nr_indeksu through User model. In other words execute this query (using QuerySet):

```
SELECT nr_indeksu FROM auth_user
INNER JOIN courses_student on auth_user.id = courses_student.user_id;
```

I have tried using select_related() function:

```
u = User.objects.select_related().get(pk=2)
```

but when i try to access nr_indeksu:

```
u.nr_indeksu
```

i got error that User object has no attribute (it makes sense because nr_indeksu is in Student model but shouldn't i be able to fetch it from User?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember a ForeignKey is a one-to-many relation: there are many Users for each Student. From a user object, you can access the related Students by doing `user_obj.student_set.all()`.

Comment: regarding `there are many Users for each Student.`  This should be reversed, here each Student is related to only one User, and there could be many Students for each User.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Daniel's answer, you can also use [related_names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) , right now when you have to do a reverse foreign-key lookup, you need to write :-

```
user_obj.student_set.all()
```

However, with related_name attribute, the model would look like :-

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='studentuser')
    nr_indeksu = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user
```

then for a reverse lookup, you need to write :-

```
user_obj.studentuser.all()
```

Basically, all I mean to say is, you can supply own names for reverse lookup by passing `related_name` attribute, if in case you don't want to use the default name used by django which is generally of the form `<foreign_key_name>_set` eg. in your case it is `student_set`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s =  Student.objects.get(user__id=2)

s.nr_indeksu
```

Comment: The thing is i want to fetch nr_indeksu from User model using JOIN and FK relationship, you answer is just simple SELECT WHERE from Student model

Comment: Nope, it's not. `user__id=2` means `Select * from USER where user_id=2;`. It's like a subquery.

Comment: Ok i see, thanks - but still I'd like to acces Student properties from User object